# <input> element in tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I want to have `input` element in my editor so user can type something in it. I've tried just write html in my textarea but the `input` element goes unclickable ([ex1](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Pbeaab))

```
Value: <input type='text' value='12.3'> kg
```

I've also tried to make `contenteditable="true"` div and input worked in it without problems, so it is tinymce problem ([ex2](http://jsfiddle.net/m87k6/))

I can't use `input` in editor even if I initialize tinymce with div and set html manually

```
ed.getBody().innerHTML = "Value: <input type='text' value='12.3'> kg"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an input element into textarea element.

Try

```
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <label for="kgElement">Value:</label>
    <input type='text' id="kgElement" placeholder='12.3'> kg
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're having the Input field inside the `textarea` element. Which itself is fully editable.

Take it out of the textarea, and then it would work just the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this effect by adding 'code' in toolbar and plugins.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea.codedemo',
  plugins: 'code',
  toolbar: 'code',
});
```

this adds an option 'source code' under tinymce Tools option in the toolbar menu . The source code allows you to add custom inputs
Also take a look in the docs
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/enterprise/advcode/